# C++11 initialize array with uniform value in constexpr function

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I have a class template which builds a simple array based on the template parameters as one of its members.  I need to be able to initialize every element in the array to a single value in one of the constructors.  Unfortunately this constructor must be `constexpr`.

The relevant part boils down to:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
class foo
{
  T data[N];

  constexpr foo(T val)
  {
    // initialize data with N copies of val
  }
};
```

Using `std::fill` or a loop is incompatible with the `constexpr` requirement.  Initializing with `: data{val}` only sets the first element of the array and zero-initializes the remainder.

How can this be achieved?

I feel like there should be a solution with variadic templates and tuples etc...

Comment: @BryanChen: Not so much, that question isn't about `constexpr`

Comment: There's a straightforward way to achieve what you want if constructor argument of "foo(T val)" could be turned into a template argument "template <T val> foo()".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather curiously, a solution for the problem exists in c++14 (compile the example with `-std=c++1y` on gcc; also see comments for a bit more verbose c++11 solution by Praetorian):

```
template <size_t N>
struct bar {
    template <typename T, typename ...Tn>
    static constexpr auto apply(T v, Tn ...vs)
    {
        return bar<N - 1>::apply(v, v, vs...);
    }
};

template <>
struct bar<1> {
    template <typename T, typename ...Tn>
    static constexpr auto apply(T v, Tn ...vs)
    {
        return std::array<T, sizeof...(vs) + 1>{v, vs...};
    }

};

template <typename T, size_t N>
struct foo {
    std::array<T, N> data;

    constexpr foo(T val)
    : data(bar<N>::apply(val))
    {}
};
```

(I replaced the POD array with std::array - suppose it should not make any problems for your use case).

Live example is here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4731a10ee54563b9

Comment: +1 Works with `-std=c++11` also if you specify the return types for the functions. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/668bd7f546654971

Comment: Of course - somehow `decltype()` had slipped my mind.

Answer (score 6):

You may use the following: (https://ideone.com/xTacMP)

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename T, std::size_t...Is>
    constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> make_array(T val, index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        return {(static_cast<void>(Is), val)...};
    }
}

template <std::size_t N, typename T>
constexpr std::array<T, N> make_array(T val)
{
    return detail::make_array(val, make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

And then call it:

```
constexpr foo(T val) : data(make_array<N>(val)) {}
```