# how to initialize a large size of std::array

Tags: c++

i have a class,the class contains a large size of std::array,how to initialize the array??

see class test;

sample:

```
class context{......}

class value
{
public:
    value(context& ctx) : ctx_(ctx){
    }

protected:
    context& ctx_;

    int data_ = 0;
}


class test
{
public:
    test() : /*i need to initialize values at here*/ values_{ctx_,.....}
    {
    }

protected:
    context ctx_;
    std::array<value_t,10000> values_;
}
```

in reality,this array maybe only contains 3 or 5 element,not 10000,but someof people definitely gonna give me an answer like below

```
test() : values_{ctx_,ctx_,ctx_,ctx_,ctx_}
{
}
```

i don't need a awkward answer like above.

is there a way to initialize std::array with simple code like fold expression???

Comment: Do you require each element of the `array` initialized because you need each `element` ready to use immediately? Or, can you deal with uninitialized values that can be initialized at a later time?

Comment: FWIW, if you don't mind a single memory allocation, `auto values = std::vector<value_t>(ctx_, 10000);` does what you want.

Comment: Related to [c11-initialize-array-with-uniform-value-in-constexpr-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901394/c11-initialize-array-with-uniform-value-in-constexpr-function)

Answer (score 1):

You can delegate to a constructor that takes a parameter pack then fold over that:

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>

class test
{
public:
    test() : test(std::make_index_sequence<10000>{}) {}
private:
    template<std::size_t... I>
    test(std::index_sequence<I...>) : values_{{(I, ctx_)...}} {}
protected:
    context ctx_;
    std::array<value_t, 10000> values_;
};
```

Though this absolutely *killed* compile time at any level of optimisation other than `-O0` for me (And will probably blow up your compiled code size)

You could also try constructing into uninitialised memory so you don't need to default construct:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <new>
#include <memory>

class test
{
public:
    test() {
        std::byte* p = value_memory_;
        for (std::byte* end = std::end(value_memory_); p < end; p += sizeof(value_t)) {
            new (p) value_t(ctx_);
        }
    }

    ~test() {
        value_t* values = get_values();
        std::destroy(values, values + 10000);
    }
protected:
    context ctx_;

    value_t* get_values() {
        return std::launder(reinterpret_cast<value_t*>(value_memory_));
    }
    const value_t* get_values() const {
        return std::launder(reinterpret_cast<const value_t*>(value_memory_));
    }

    // These are UB, but work on most compilers, and would generally be nicer
    // to work with
    value_t(&get_values())[10000] {
        return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<value_t(*)[10000]>(value_memory_));
    }
    const value_t(&get_values() const)[10000] {
        return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<const value_t(*)[10000]>(value_memory_));
    }
private:
    alignas(value_t) std::byte value_memory_[sizeof(value_t) * 10000u];
};
```

Which will have some runtime cost, and you have to lose the `std::array` (Unless you go for a `std::array<std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(value_t), alignof(value_t)>, 10000>`, in which case you have to launder every single element of the array)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your array holds elements of a type that does not have a default constructor, so when you declare a `std::array` holding that type, the array can only be initialized using [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) so you can explicitly pass in a value to each element's constructor.  When the array is a member of a class or struct, that initialization requires use of the class/struct constructor's [member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).  Exactly what you are trying to avoid.

To get around this, you can use [`placement-new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) to explicitly construct each array element individually in a loop:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

class context{......}

class value
{
public:
    value(context& ctx) : ctx_(ctx){
    }

protected:
    context& ctx_;

    int data_ = 0;
}


class test
{
public:
    test()
    {
        for (auto &v : values_)
            new (&v) value(ctx_);
    }

    ~test()
    {
        for (auto &v : values_) {
            // note: needs std::launder in C++17 and later
            // std::launder(reinterpret_cast<value*>(&v))->~value();
            reinterpret_cast<value*>(&v)->~value();
        }
    }

protected:
    context ctx_;

    using storage_type = std::aligned_storage<sizeof(value), alignof(value)>::type;
    std::array<storage_type, 10000> values_;

    // Access an object in aligned storage
    value& operator[](std::size_t pos)
    {
        // note: needs std::launder in C++17 and later
        // return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<value*>(&values_[pos]));
        return *reinterpret_cast<value*>(&values_[pos]);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fill() method on the array:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/fill

Comment: The array in question needs to be initialized before it can be filled, but `value` does not have a default constructor, so the `values_` array can't be initialized.